# Is it a unnecessary while statement in prescan function of the MediaScanner?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mediastore

when I read Android 4.4 Source Code, I found this function has two while statement,  according to the where sentence (where = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID + ">?"), once query ,the SQlite will return all result,So I think the first while statement is useless.Is it true ?

```html
    private void prescan(String filePath, boolean prescanFiles) throws RemoteException {
        Cursor c = null;
        String where = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;

        if (mPlayLists == null) {
            mPlayLists = new ArrayList<FileEntry>();
        } else {
            mPlayLists.clear();
        }

        if (filePath != null) {
            // query for only one file
            where = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID + ">?" +
                " AND " + Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[] { "", filePath };
        } else {
            where = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID + ">?";
            selectionArgs = new String[] { "" };
        }
  
        Uri.Builder builder = mFilesUri.buildUpon();
        builder.appendQueryParameter(MediaStore.PARAM_DELETE_DATA, "false");
        MediaBulkDeleter deleter = new MediaBulkDeleter(mMediaProvider, mPackageName,
                builder.build());

        // Build the list of files from the content provider
        try {
            if (prescanFiles) {
                long lastId = Long.MIN_VALUE;
                Uri limitUri = mFilesUri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("limit", "1000").build();
                mWasEmptyPriorToScan = true;

                while (true) {
                    selectionArgs[0] = "" + lastId;
                    if (c != null) {
                        c.close();
                        c = null;
                    }
                    c = mMediaProvider.query(mPackageName, limitUri, FILES_PRESCAN_PROJECTION,
                            where, selectionArgs, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID, null);
                    if (c == null) {
                        break;
                    }

                    int num = c.getCount();

                    if (num == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    mWasEmptyPriorToScan = false;
                    while (c.moveToNext()) {
                        long rowId = c.getLong(FILES_PRESCAN_ID_COLUMN_INDEX);
                        String path = c.getString(FILES_PRESCAN_PATH_COLUMN_INDEX);
                        int format = c.getInt(FILES_PRESCAN_FORMAT_COLUMN_INDEX);
                        long lastModified = c.getLong(FILES_PRESCAN_DATE_MODIFIED_COLUMN_INDEX);
                        lastId = rowId;
...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
...
    }
```

thank you for watching.

Comment: Do you have a link to the full source code ? Those "..." might offer a clue.

Answer (score 0):

> So I think the first while statement is useless.Is it true ?

It is not useless. This code is not the only code running in the system.

Consider what happens if new content gets added to the media provider while still processing the result set of a previous query. Without the first while loop that content would not get scanned yet. With the loop in place, it is taken into account immediately.